# 4 rebuses – 1 topic

Tags: word, visual, rebus

The four pictures below refers to a word each.
All four words come under the same topic.

[image: Picture of 4 rebuses]

Can you identify all four words and the topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the topic might be

> Military aviation slang/buzz phrases

1. > Mayday - Distress call, comes from the French M’aidez (help me).
2. > Dogfight - Aerial engagement with the enemy, usually at close range
3. > Bandit (from one-armed bandit or slot machine) - The bad guy in the dogfight ie the enemy
4. > Fox, or more specifically Fox 1 - call given to indicate launch of an air-to-air missile (Fox 1 indicating launch of sparrow missile, as opposed to fox 2 or fox 3)

Comment: A perfect answer!

Answer (score 4):

Topic:

> flowers

1. 

> **maypop** - month of may with the last day 'popped' (in a programming sense).

2. 

> **wolfsbane** - wolves having a fight. Wolf plural + bane (which means torment).

3. 

> **bouncing bet** - another name for Saponaria officinalis. What appears to be bouncing balls are inside a machine used for betting.

4. 

> **red fox** - a variety of Veronica Spicata.

Comment: Well-thought answers (+1), but none too close.

Comment: Might not be intended, but I'm impressed. But also glad I can still take a stab at it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the topic could be..

> **Rally**

Because..

> Pic1 - **may day**, where rallies usually take place worldwide. Pic2 - **clash**, clashes are likely to happen during rallies. Pic3 - **bandit**(from one armed bandit), usually bandits are gang-members and some operates in large groups and engage in rallies(bandidos, hells angels, etc..). Pic4 - **Fox**, I associate this with "Fox News". Not unusal to see different type of rallies on the news.